# SSRS main and sub report parameter issue

Tags: ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 BIDS to create a report that contains a sub report. This is only the second ssrs report I've created so forgive me if I'm not using the correct terminology. Right now when I try to preview the report in BIDS I get this error message:

```
[rsWarningExecutingSubreport] Warnings occurred while executing the subreport         ‘lineItemsSubReport’.
[rsNone] The report parameter 'salesOrderId' is read-only and cannot be modified.
[rsNone] The report parameter 'salesOrderId' is read-only and cannot be modified.
[rsNone] The report parameter 'salesOrderId' is read-only and cannot be modified.
[rsNone] The report parameter 'salesOrderId' is read-only and cannot be modified.
```

On the subreport, my parameter was set to internal, but I have changed to it hidden.

I'm using FetchXMl for the query for both reports.

My main report contains a data set that has a field called salesorderid. I'm trying to pass this value to the sub report doing this:

```
<Subreport Name="lineItemsSubReport">
  <ReportName>LineItemsSubReport</ReportName>
     <Parameters>
        <Parameter Name="salesOrderId">
           <Value>=Fields!salesOrder_salesorderid.Value</Value>
        </Parameter>
     </Parameters>
     <Top>0.38542in</Top>
     <Left>0.125in</Left>
     <Height>0.62499in</Height>
     <Width>5.98958in</Width>
     <ZIndex>1</ZIndex>
     <Style>
        <Border>
            <Style>None</Style>
        </Border>
      </Style>
</Subreport>
```

In my sub report I have a filter on the query and a Query Parameter named salesOrderId and a Report Parameter called salesOrderId. Is this setup right? If not how do I setup the sub report to get the parameter that is passed from the main report? This seems like it should be easy, but it's being a bit of a pain.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well I somehow got it to work, but I'm not quite sure what excatly I did that did it. I will post the answer if I figure it out.